# Send Email with Different Accounts

Tags: 7, emails

I've been searching but didn't find much.

Is there any module or way to send emails with Drupal, but using different email accounts?

For example, I have a site which will have 3 different email accounts to send email.
User A creates a node, the user will receive an email from the email account 1.
User B takes an action, he or she will receive an email from the email account 2.
Etc.

To sum up:

Is there any module to hold different email accounts in one drupal site and send email with them?

I've seen some modules to hold different email accounts for the users, but not for the site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question  you are right  no module for that . but  you can configure it by rules 
like
after saving node 
add action - sand e-mail userA
on this add conditions according to your need 
like  account type userA
I think this is the possible way for that

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That could be a possible solution, but the problem is the account which sends the email, it must be different depending on the case. Changing the From field of the email without changing the email which truly sends the email will trigger the spam filters.

Comment: well for this we have use token

Comment: But token is different if  userA is like seller type  userB is buyer type so we can create  token for email and then  add action on it

Comment: I'm afraid that creating a token to change the From field will not solve the problem, still we can't change the email account from where the messages are sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_mail_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7.x) for altering the from email address. You can check the message id accordingly and change the from address.

```
function MODULE_NAME_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if (isset($message['id']) && !empty($message['id'])) {
    if ($message['id'] == 'your condition') {
      $message['from'] = $message['headers']['From'] = 'your email address';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Tried this and tried with the $message['headers']['Sender'] = $message['headers']['Return-Path'] fields too. 
The problem is that the email is rejected because of spoofing, we are sending always with the same account, and changing "on-the-fly" some of the fields. 
We send with email1@mail.com, but we need to send with email2@mail.com too. 
Unfortunately changing the headers does not solve the problem.